# react-table selectbox filtering

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-table

table plugin https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table

how i can filter my column with select box ? eg:

i have column and there is just two name 
Name 1
Name 2

I want to put selectbox to column for select and filtering my NAME 1 or NAME 2 entries.

```
{Header: 'Owner',accessor: 'name', headerClassName: 'wordwrap', Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) =>
        <select
          onChange={event => onChange(event.target.value)}
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          value={filter ? filter.value : "all"}
        >
          <option value="all">Show All</option>
          <option value="true">Name 1</option>
          <option value="false">Name 2</option>
        </select>
        },
```

I found in example something and implemented to my code. But I don't know how put options from my accessor

Comment: Explain your question

Comment: I explained here

Comment: Is it something like this that you are after 
`https://codesandbox.io/s/v878xvjq70`

Comment: @Sid amazing, thanks!